# make a post request out of an angular ui-modal

Tags: json, angularjs, http, bootstrap-modal

I have made an angular modal as a directive.  My goal is to make a post request to a json file with the given form data.  I am not sure how to set up the post request.  I read that $http takes care of JSON.stringify() for me so I do not need to configure the data for the post.  I am also wondering if I need to set up my header? Below is my much of the data that I have.

I made a json file to hold an array that I got a beer list from.

The addBeer() function is where I would ideally make the post request in the factory

As it stands now I am setting up my function like so

```
function addBeer() {
            return $http.post(url,{
                data: JSON.stringify({}),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log('response', response);
            })


        }
```

This will be part of a factory.  In the overall factory I am following the John papa style guide.   **getBeerList()** is getting the entire json file, while  **getBeer()** is getting each individual beer that I am looking for.

```
   (function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('beerApp.services.beerList',[])
        .factory('beerListFactory', beerListFactory);

        beerListFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$log'];

        function beerListFactory($http, $log) {
            var url = './app/Services/IBU_list.json';

            return {
                getBeerList: getBeerList,
                getBeer: getBeer,
                addBeer: addBeer

            }

            function getBeerList(){

                return $http.get(url, {catch: true})
                    .then(getBeerListComplete)
                    .catch(getBeerListFailed);

                    function getBeerListComplete(response) {

                        return response.data;
                    }

                    function getBeerListFailed(error) {
                        console.log('error', error);
                    }
            }

            function getBeer(id) {
                return $http.get(url, {
                    catch: true
                })
                .then(getBeerComplete)

                function getBeerComplete(response) {
                    console.log('promise', id);
                    console.log('response', response.data.length);
                    var data = response.data;
                    for(var i =0, len=data.length;i<len;i++) {
                        console.log(typeof data[i].id)
                        if(data[i].id == parseInt(id)) {
                            console.log('data i',data[i]);
                            return data[i];
                        }
                    }
                } // end of getBeerComplete
            } //end of getBeer

            function addBeer() {
                return $http.post(url,{
                    data: JSON.stringify({}),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log('response', response);
                })


            }
        } // end of beer Factory
})();
```

The overall goal is to push into a json array that has objects set like so:

```
{
"id" : "4",
"BeerStyle": "American Light Lager",
"IBU": "8-17",
"list" : {"drinks": []}
```

},

Each drink in the form should go into the  **"drinks" array**

Inside of my Modal Instance Contrl I am checking for the form values that I have set with

```
vm.newBeer = {};
```

Here is the function I commented out the addBeer Function but this is what I would ideally do with the post request

```
function ModalInstanceCtrl( $scope,$modalInstance) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.ok = ok; 
            vm.cancel = cancel; 
            vm.newBeer = {};
            // vm.addBeer = function() {

            // }

            function ok () {
                console.log('new beer', vm.newBeer);
                // console.log('IBU',$scope.IBU);
                console.log('clicked');
                $modalInstance.close();
            };

            function cancel() {
                console.log('beer', vm.newBeer);

                console.log('clicked');
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }
```

I am getting the values inside of the console correctly

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="beer" ng-model="vm.newBeer.beerName">
```

Inside of my directive I directive I am calling the get request I made for a single beer.  I was doing this to make sure I had it set and could connect to a controller.  I am thinking that the post request would take place in the resolve.

```
   function ModalController($modal, $log , $scope, beerListFactory, $stateParams) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.animationsEnabled = true;
            vm.open = open;

            function open() {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    animation: vm.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/modal/modal.html',
                    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    bindToController: true,
                    size: 'lg'
                    // resolve: {
                    //  title: function() {
                    //      return 'training Info';
                    //  }
                    // }            
                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
                    $log.info('beer in modal',beerListFactory.getBeer($stateParams.beerId) );

                    console.log("Confirmed: "+ selectedItem);
                    $scope.selectedItem = selectedItem;
                }, function() {
                    $log.info('modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                });
            };
```

Comment: Change addBeer to: function addBeer() {
 return $http.post(url,{
  data: JSON.stringify({}),
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
 })
 .then(function(response) {
  console.log('Sucess: ', response);
 }, function(error){
  console.log('Error: ', response);
 });
}, this show erros ocurred in post

Comment: @EmirMarques I expect to get a method not allowed.  Which is what I am getting.  I am not sure exactly how to set this up.  I need to push the newBeer object  into the array assigned to drinks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSON, I would recommend using Angular's [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) factory.

> The returned resource object has action methods which provide
>   high-level behaviors without the need to interact with the low level
>   $http service.

Instead of `$http.get()` and `$http.post()`, you can use `Beer.query()` and `Beer.save()`.  `$resource` was designed for services like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have *finally* succeeded in doing this.

**HTML**

```
<!--MODAL WINDOW for item details -->
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="itemModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-dialog " ng-class="{fadeOut: startFade}" ng-hide="hidden">
             <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="cancel right button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="cancel()"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
                       <span class="item-name">{{item.name}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                       <p class="description">{{item.description}}</p>
                       <input type="hidden" ng-model="item.uniqueid" id="itemid" value="{{item.courseid}}" name="itemid"/>
                       <p class="response"> {{PostDataResponse}}</p>
                       <p class="error"> {{ResponseDetails}}</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="button cancel btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="button ok btn-primary" ng-click="confirm()">Sign me up</button> 
                  </div>
               </div>
           </div>
      </script>
```

**Angular**

```
myApp.controller('itemModalInstanceCtrl', function ($http, $scope, $uibModalInstance, $timeout, item) {
    $scope.item = item;
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
        $('.overlay').hide();
    };

    updateUrl = '<your URL to post to>';

    $scope.confirm = function () {

        var myItemId = $scope.item.uniqueid;

       // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON
        var data = $.param({
            uniqueid: myItemId
        });
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post(updateUrl, data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                $scope.PostDataResponse = "You have signed up!";
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $('.response').addClass('error');
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "data: " + data +
                        "<br />status: " + status +
                        "<br />headers: " + header +
                        "<br />config: " + config;
            });
            $timeout(function() {
                $uibModalInstance.close({});
                $('.overlay').hide();
            }, 3000);
    };

});
```

The secret is not to pass in the `$scope` or the `$http` injection to the confirm function but to reference `$scope.item.property` **in full** inside the function. Hope this helps someone!